# Set cipher suites used by WinHTTP

Tags: c++, http, ssl, openssl, winhttp

I would like to use WinHTTP to verify the correctness of some cipher suites which are a modified version of OpenSSL ciphers.

However, I am not able to force WinHTTP to use a specific cipher when contacting a TLS/SSL server. I tried a couple of things, but none worked.

Here is what I tried:

1. Using the CryptoAPI to remove cipher suites: I basically removed all cipher suites and added the one I wanted to test using the API functions: `BCryptAddContextFunction()` and `BCryptRemoveContextFunction()`. Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
2. Followed instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930(v=vs.85).aspx) to in the section "To configure the SSL Cipher Suite Order group policy setting".

But none of these worked. Is there any clue how to do this?

btw, I am using Windows 7 Enterprise. And I am verifying what ciphers are being used using Wireshark.

Thank you in advance.